# Customer review on product type

Tags: product, customer, review, product-review, product-type

I'm working with a shop which sells used Products. I want the customer reviews be visible on a "product type" page: An example:
If i have used a used laptop msi ge60 with several hardware configurations. I want the customer review for each used msi ge60 no matter what kind of hardware features it has. If i delete one of these used msi ge60 or it is out of stock i want the review still be visible on that certain type of msi ge60.

I hope you can help me, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Hi dlayne and welcome to MageOverflow!

I would think about creating a "generic" product for each type, then add the reviews there and just create a widget which adds the review were you want it.

You can then link the generic product with an attribute in all your products.